# Ruby IF no ARGV given

Tags: ruby

This is my code:

```
if ARGV[0] == false
    puts "Usage: ./script.rb argument"
    exit
end
print "Yey we got an argument: " ARGV[0]
```

But I just cant make the code check if ARGV[0] is given or not, how should I do that ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Check if it's `empty?` (or check its length):

```
if ARGV.empty?
  puts ...
  exit
end
```

Consider using any of the Ruby command line argument parsers, like [OptionParser](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html).

Comment: Does OptionParser handle positional arguments?  I've only been able to get it to parse switches.

Comment: @WayneConrad For that you can just use ARGV.

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way to process positional arguments (other than using a gem to do it) is to [shift](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-shift) them off, one at a time:

```
arg1 = ARGV.shift
arg2 = ARGV.shift
```

A missing argument will be nil.  Let's exploit that to give arg2 a default value:

```
arg1 = ARGV.shift
arg2 = ARGV.shift || 'default value goes here'
```

Checking for a required argument is trivial:

```
raise "missing argument" unless arg1
```

It's also easy to see if too many arguments have been supplied:

```
raise "too many arguments" unless ARGV.empty?
```

Comment: This is really terse and expressive:
arg2 = ARGV.shift || 'default value goes here'

Thanks for this!

Comment: This is bad code since it breaks with a false value in ARGV. Example: `args=[false]; a=args.shift||true;` Here `a` has final value `true` but it should be `false`.

Comment: @KomodoDave - Ruby only puts strings into ARGV

Comment: @WayneConrad Thank you for this info - I simply applied my technique for any array to ARGV. At least the comment will inform others that this approach isn't applicable to standard arrays.

Answer (score 6):

I realize a good solution is already given, but nobody mentioned the real reason why your example didn't work.

The issue with your example code is that if there are no arguments given, `ARGV[0]` will return `nil`, and `nil == false` is false. `nil` is "falsy", but not equal to false. What you could have done is:

```
unless ARGV[0]
  puts "Usage: ..."
  exit 1
end
```

Which would have worked, because this statement now depends on falsyness, rather than on equality to the actual `false`.

But don't use this code, it's far more clear if you state your actual intent, which is that you want to know if there are any arguments (instead of whether the first argument is falsy). So use the code others suggested:

```
if ARGV.empty?
  puts "Usage..."
  exit 1
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if ARGV[0] (or more args) is given or not:

```
puts 'Usage: ...' if ARGV.length == 0
```

You could also use ARGV.empty? (@DaveNewton's answer)

Comment: I also mentioned checking length.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length of `ARGV`. If it has zero elements then `ARGV[0]` wasn't given.

Answer (score 0):

I do this and work's:

```
url = ARGV[0] 

if url.nil?
  puts "The shell script needs the arguments."
  exit
end
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's what I do:

```
a = 'defaultvalue' if (a = ARGV.shift).nil?
```

Someone else suggested this:

```
a = ARGV.shift || 'defaultvalue'
```

This is wrong, since any false value will cause `defaultvalue` to be assigned, e.g.:

```
args=[false]; a=args.shift||true; # a has final value true when it should be false
```

Comment: This is needlessly complex.  The code you oppose is correct, since Ruby only puts strings into ARGV.

Comment: What I've said is correct for any array except ARGV and also works for ARGV. Why have an approach different for ARGV than for any other array?

Comment: Because we know what's in ARGV?